# How to extract R-squared from plotly px.scatter trendline result?

Tags: python, plotly, scatter

how can I extract R-squared value from the following summary():

```
import plotly.express as px
df = ...
fig = px.scatter(df, x="...", y="...", trendline="ols") 
a = px.get_trendline_results(fig).px_fit_results.iloc[0].summary()
```

I know how to extract coefficients of trendline with **params**:[coef in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O84E1.png)

```
print(fit_results.params)
```

but I need to extract R-squared value from the results to annotate it in static saved figs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found it :)

```
a = px.get_trendline_results(fig).px_fit_results.iloc[0].rsquared
```

that's it.

Comment: The simplest solution!